# Htaccess rewrite rule file extension

Tags: .htaccess

I want to write htaccess rewrite rule wherein if incoming url has .html or .php file extension at the end then redirect the page to homepage(/).

For example: if url is /abc/a.html redirect to homepage(/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(php|html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ / [R]
```

This will match **any** URL with `.php` or `.html` at the end and redirects to `/`

You can simply add extensions that should be matched like this: `(php|html|htm)`

Comment: This answer a different question i had. I was wondering how to redirect an array (list) of extension. Just to explain, the RewriteCond check if the reuested url ends (after the last dot) with one of the extension inside the brackets. If so it redirect it. In my case i will use it to redirect image request buy using something like `.*\.(jpg!jpeg|png|ico|gif)` and redirect those to the media subdomain using `RewriteRule (.*) http://img.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

This one should help

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ https://domain.test/$1.myextension[R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$  https://domain.test/$1.myextension[R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$  https://domain.test/$1.myextension[R=301,L]
```